# Python .pop() Is Not Working

Tags: python

I've gotten a little rusty with python. A friend is taking some tests to prepare for his exams and he's given this piece of code:

```
stack = [3, 4, 5]

stack.append(6)

stack.pop()
```

He's asked what will the screen show and the correct answer is 7. How is it 7? I've even written the code and run it. It is 6. Is it a new version returning the number + 1 or something? Or maybe the answers given by their teacher are just wrong.

Comment: You `append(5)` and then you `pop()` it... So it will print `6`.

Comment: Sounds like something crucial may have been lost in transmission between the original assignment and what you've posted here. What you've posted here would not print 7.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
[3,4,5,6].pop()
```

Neither Python 2 nor Python 3 return `7` (both return `6`).
The most obvious answer is that it was just a typo by the teacher or your friend when they sent you the example.

---

```
[3,4,5,6].pop()
```

is equivalent to

```
[3,4,5,6].pop(-1)
```

Both return the last (= top) element of a stack.

---

With `[3,4,5].append(6)` 
you append a `6` to the stack → you push the `6` on top of the stack.

Therefore if you execute

```
stack = [3,4,5]
stack.append(6)
stack.pop()       # equ. to stack.pop(-1)
```

the result will be `6` and cannot be `7`.

---

For a more detailed explanation of how and why lists in python can be used as various datastructures (stack, queue, ...) consider taking a look at the documentation:
https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html

Comment: The answer is accepted as correct but please provide a brief explanation of why pop returns 6 and not 7 :)

Answer (score 1):

The answer that is given by the teacher is wrong.

> list.pop([i]) - Remove the item at the given position in the list, and
>   return it. If no index is specified, a.pop() removes and returns the
>   last item in the list.

Take a look at [the documentation of pop](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#more-on-lists)

```
stack = [3, 4, 5]
stack.append(6)
print(stack.pop())
print(stack)
```

Output:

```
6
[3, 4, 5]
```

Comment: The answer is accepted as correct but please provide a brief explanation of how pop works rather than a link :)

Answer (score 1):

I've running your code here, using CMD and python 3.6.2, and this is the output:

```
>>> stack = [3,4,5]
>>> stack.append(6)
>>> stack.pop()
6
>>>
```

Surely, the correct answer is `6`

Answer (score 0):

This must be a trick question

```
stack = [3, 4, 5]

stack.append(6)

stack.pop()
```

returns

`6`

This is because you `append` 6 to the `end` or `top` of the `stack / list / array`.

A `pop` command follows the `last in first out` rule which means when  you `pop` an item from the `stack / list /array` you will be taking out the last item.

Therefore with `6` being the last item appended, when you `pop` the `stack` the return will be the last item, in this instance `6`